# LLVM - Run Own Pass automatically with clang

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I wrote a few own passes for llvm, in order to use them with clang.

I integrated them in llvm (not dynamically loaded). They are even listed in the *Optimizations available:* section when I type:

```
opt --help-hidden
```

I want to run one of own my passes now automatically as the **last one** when I call clang:

```
clang ./hello.bc -o ./hello
```

or even with c-code:

```
clang ./hello.c -o ./hello
```

When I run my pass with opt manually, the modified ByteCode is generated and written to a new .bc file:

```
opt -my-pass < ./hello.bc > ./hello_optimized.bc
```

When I compile the modified .bc with clang, normal clang Optimizations are run again, which destroy the optimizations of my manual executed pass:

```
clang -O0 -m32 ./hello_optimized.bc -o ./hello_optimized
```

My Question is:

- How can I run my own written pass automatically with clang as the last pass of all?
- Another possible solution is deactivating all passes completely, or at least the dead code/function elimination of clang/opt. How could I do this?

Comment: Use clang -flto, and pass your sequence of passes to the gold lto plugin.

Answer (score 5):

You can run your own pass with clang directly with -Xclang.

```
clang++ -Xclang -load -Xclang ./libmypass.so input.cpp
```

[Source](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/clangpass.html)

Comment: This is the best answer. You just have to add `-flegacy-pass-manager` for newer versions of clang. The new pass manager doesn't seem to allow automatic registration.

Comment: The most recent clang has dropped the legacy pass manager.
See new approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447985/how-to-automatically-register-and-load-modern-pass-in-clang/75999804#75999804

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this would be to make clang add your pass to the pass manager it builds. See `clang/lib/CodeGen/BackendUtil.cpp:void EmitAssemblyHelper::CreatePasses()` for how it's handled for the sanitizers.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, the legacy pass manager is dropped.
I wrote here a full example with clang + new pass manager (works for me).
[working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447985/how-to-automatically-register-and-load-modern-pass-in-clang/75999804#75999804)